# modification to comment environment

Tags: environments, comments, notes

I'm using the [comment package](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comment/comment.pdf), in my preamble I have

`\specialcomment{notes}{\begingroup \color{Blue}}{\endgroup}`

so that when I want to comment my text I write

`\begin{notes}...\end{notes}`

to get a blue output.
Because I need to print in black and white, it would be useful for the comments to be clearer in text. So I would like to get this to produce a line break, bold text saying "Notes:" and another line break at the end of my comment. I would also like to still be able to type

`\excludecomment{notes}`

to get rid of all my comments, without affecting the spacing of the text (as it would be without any notes).

Since I don't know anything about latex programming, I was hoping someone could help me, as experts on this site have been of great help to me in the past. Solutions that don't use the package I have at the moment would be fine as well. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define the `notes` environment to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,comment}

\newenvironment{notes}
 {\par\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries Note:} \color{blue}\ignorespaces}
 {\par}

%\excludecomment{notes}

\begin{document}

Some text for saying some nonsense.
\begin{notes}
Here we want to add a note.
\end{notes}
Start again with nonsense.

\bigskip

\excludecomment{notes}

Some text for saying some nonsense.
\begin{notes}
Here we want to add a note.
\end{notes}
Start again with nonsense.

\end{document}
```

Uncommenting the `\excludecomment` line will hide the `notes` environment, like in the emulation in the second part of the example.

[image]

The flow is interrupted, but this is a limitation of the `comment` package. When you are finished and remove the `notes` environments, you can reestablish the correct flow.

Note: I issued twice the color instruction, because it's better not to have `\color` after `\par` if it's possible to avoid it. However,

```
\newenvironment{notes}
 {\par\leavevmode\color{blue}{\bfseries Note:} \ignorespaces}
 {\par}
```

would be the same.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: One last thing... I think I understand the issue about the flow being interrupted (so I will eventually have to manually get rid of all comments, correct?), but it would look a bit nicer if the paragraph after my notes wasn't indented. Please don't bother about this if it would entail a completely new solution, the one you wrote up in your answer is fine.

Comment: Use `{\par\noindent\ignorespacesafterend}` in the “final” part of the definition of the environment, instead of just `{\par}`.